# Spanish subtitles for Tron: The next day

Tags: tron

Does a Spanish subtitled version of *Tron: The Next Day* exist?

Alternatively, are there Spanish transcriptions or subtitles available?

---

*Tron: The Next Day* is a 10 minute short film "bridge" between Tron 2 and Tron 3.

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xhkp04_tron-the-next-day-flynn-lives-revealed-tr3n-teaser-1_shortfilms

Comment: Are you asking if there *is* a copy (DVD, Bluray, digital) that has Spanish subtitles, or where to purchase one?  Shopping recommendations are generally considered off-topic, but asking if one exists would probably be on-topic.

Comment: @Tony Meyer: Where to buy would be off topic. But presumably this is asking what, if any, place can I obtain a Spanish Subtitled version of Tron: The Next Day.

Comment: I'll be happy to just get a text file with the subs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have better luck to request them in [SubDivX](http://www.subdivx.com/) or [Argenteam](http://www.argenteam.net/) because those are sites dedicated on subtitles.

Good luck.